# can i use bitwise on the entire char array?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

can i use bitwise on the entire char array?

working example:

```c
   unsigned int aNumInt= 0xFFFF; //1111111111111111
   aNumInt = aNumInt << 8; // 1111111100000000
```

is it possible to do the same with an entire array of char?

***NOT*** working example:

```c
     unsigned char aCharInt[2]={0xFF,0xFF}; //1111111111111111
     aCharInt = aCharInt << 8; //<-- this does not work.. using it as an example
     // 1111111100000000
```

or do is the only way to go is by going with byte per byte

`aCharInt[1] = aCharInt[1] << 8;`
or `memcpy`

Comment: Are you looking to shift each element separately, or do you want to shift bits between elements?

Comment: It does not work like that. You would modify the pointer value, not the pointed-to value(s). You might want to do a `memmove` though.

Comment: @interhay to shift between element

Comment: nope in general. But you could cast in chunks of 2 or 4 (depending on size of int, long, long long etc). But unless this is a) perf critical b) demonstrably slow) i wouldn't do it just to save typing

Comment: It's pretty likely this is an XY-problem. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Cheatah moving an element up from index[0] to index[1] using bitwise, or moving the element down

Comment: To move items in an array, use `memmove`. Or use something like a linked list or queue that is more suitable for such operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can seldom operate on all the elements of an array at once in C.  One of the few exceptions is if you have an array that is part of a structure; then you can copy the elements of the array as part of a structure assignment.  But that doesn't apply here.

Shift operations or other bitwise operators would have to be applied to each element in turn.